# default configurations of installing mysql on ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: mysql

I have a couple of questions about the results of installing mysql on Ubuntu 12.04 lts using sudo apt-get install mysql-server.

1) I notice the configuration file is installed in the following location:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

According to the mysql documentation (http://dev.mysql.com):

"The settings will be considered global to all MySQL servers if stored in /etc/my.cnf. It will be global to a specific server if located in the directory where the MySQL databases are stored (/usr/local/mysql/data for a binary installation, or /usr/local/var for a source installation)."

Seeing that its not installed in neither of these locations, are my settings global to a specific server or all mysql servers (not sure what it means by "all").

2) The my.cnf points to the mysql socket, but it does it three times:

```
[client]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

What is the difference between client, mysqld_safe, and mysqld?

3) var/lib/mysql is where database data is stored. But it's only accessible as root by default:

```
ls -l | grep mysql
drwx------ 5 mysql
```

Should it only be accessibly by root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Debian/Ubuntu ship my.cnf in a non-standard location. This is absolutely fine
2. `[client]` is read by the client, `[mysqld]` by the server and `[mysqld_safe]` by the wrapper around the mysql server that acts as a watchdog.
3. No, and it is not. It's accessible only by the mysql user, your ls output is incomplete.

Comment: When the documentation says "settings will be considered global to all MySQL servers", does that mean all mysql servers installed on that one machine? And since ubuntu ships my.cnf in a non-standard location, are the settings in the my.cnf on ubuntu still global to all servers on that machine?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Though you really should not run more than one mysqld instance on your server.